# Would Single Page Apps(thin server-thick client architectures) kill server side languages like Java, C++

Tags: web-development, web-applications

Single Page Apps strips server down to a REST api. If SPAs are the modern and better way of developing web apps, then would someday JavaScript rule the world and server-side languages like Java, C++ etc would not be the prominent skill companies look for?

Or are there still parts of huge and prominent web apps like youtube, amazon.com which just can't be all ported to client side JavaScript and would continue to depend upon server-side languages.

Comment: _Something_ still has to process those API calls. And what language is the browser you're using those SPAs on written in? The JavaScript engine itself? The client's and server's OS?

Comment: @Mat I am sorry, Maybe it was not clear in the question, I am talking about the web dev stack.

Comment: the backend that handles the API calls isn't part of the "webdev stack"? Sure that can be in JS too (node.js for instance), but that's clearly not the only option.

Comment: Its true some language might be required to create the REST api, but I guess you won't need expert skills in java, C++ etc to do that. You would aim for a very lightweight server-side framework, if any in order to create the api wrapper to the database.

Comment: This is all assuming that your app is so simple that an api wrapper to a DB would suffice, in which case, you can just do some scaffolding and be done more quickly. If on the other hand your app contains even a moderate amount of business logic, you'll soon find out that a simple api wrapper to the DB will not suffice.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, but it is a simplistic view of programming...

As said in the comments of your question, there is generally more than a simple DB access between the Rest service handler and the data.

For example, in an e-commerce application, you have to handle security, to gather the purchases related to a client, to apply some rules to compute the shipping or rebates, to propose some items related to previous purchases, to generate a PDF invoice, and so on.

There is still some logic to manage! Even if the server is "thin", it is not non-existent.
Beside, a "thick" client has limits, in speed and memory: you won't upload a big blob of data, you will paginate it, it is done on the server side. You need to keep some information confidential, and processing it on the client side is then not a good idea (a good hacker can alter the client side logic or inspect the data).

And it is not the only, dominant trend anyway. A framework like Vaadin inverts the GWT paradigm by using generic JS components, processing the logic on the server side and sending the relevant information to the client side which is then only a glue.

No, server side languages are not dead!